# Redirecting output of bash for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a simple BASH command that looks like

```
for i in `seq 2`; do echo $i; done; > out.dat
```

When this runs the output of `seq 2` is output to the terminal and nothing is output to the data file (out.dat)

I am expecting standard out to be redirected to out.dat like it does simply running the command `seq 2 > out.dat`

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Remove your semicolon.

```
for i in `seq 2`; do echo "$i"; done > out.dat
```

**SUGGESTIONS**

Also as suggested by Fredrik Pihl, try not to use external binaries when they are not needed, or at least when practically not:

```
for i in {1..2}; do echo "$i"; done > out.dat
for (( i = 1; i <= 2; ++i )); do echo "$i"; done > out.dat
for i in 1 2; do echo "$i"; done > out.dat
```

Also, be careful of outputs in `words` that may cause pathname expansion.

```
for a in $(echo '*'); do echo "$a"; done
```

Would show your files instead of just a literal `*`.

`$()` is also recommended as a clearer syntax for command substitution in Bash and POSIX shells than backticks (`` ` ``), and it supports nesting.

The cleaner solutions as well for reading output to variables are

```
while read var; do
    ...   
done < <(do something)
```

And

```
read ... < <(do something)  ## Could be done on a loop or with readarray.

for a in "${array[@]}"; do
    :
done
```

Using printf can also be an easier alternative with respect to the intended function:

```
printf '%s\n' {1..2} > out.dat
```

Comment: Why `seq` instead of `for i in {1..2}; do ...`?

Comment: @FredrikPihl Yes it's better. Or `(( i = 1 ; i <= 2; ++i ))`, or simply `in 1 2` for compatibility. My answer is only about the problem with redirection, although I tried to fix one: `"$i"`.

Comment: I just thought you could update your answer with an alternative *better* way to solve the problem without resorting to using external binaries :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl Well it's not really connected to the problem and is more of a suggestion instead, but I made an update anyway.

Comment: This example led me to realize that I can pipe the `done` statement to other things like `sort`, for example `for i in foo bar baz; do echo $i | base64; done | sort | base64 -d`

Comment: If it's really only going to be a small static straight sequence such as {1..2}, you might as well break it out into 1 2, as konsolebox said. E.g. `for a in 1 2; ...`,  `printf '%s\n' 1 2`.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility, for the sake of completeness: You can move the output inside the loop, using `>>` to append to the file, if it exists.

```
for i in `seq 2`; do echo $i >> out.dat; done;
```

Which one is better certainly depends on the use case. Writing the file in one go is certainly better than appending to it a thousand times. Also, if the loop contains multiple `echo` statements, all of which shall go to the file, doing `done > out.dat` is probably more readable and easier to maintain. The advantage of this solution, of course, is that it gives more flexibility.

Comment: Doing a single redirect outside the loop is definitely better for performance.

Comment: if you conditionally want to put to a file, it is handy to put, outputting, in the loop

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
(for i in `seq 2`; do echo $i; done;) > out.dat
```

Comment: That worked.  Is there a resource where I can read up on what the parenthesis do/why it is required. Or could you explain?

Comment: It's not necessary to place it on a subshell. The semicolon just have to be removed to make the redirection part of the block.

Comment: True, just removing the semicolon will do in this case. Subshell, ( ), can be used to collect output from larger number of commands, say multiple for-loops.

Comment: Unable to find a good subshell article on stackoverflow. Here is one external: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: @svante I agree with enclosing it around for more commands, but you could also do that with `{}` when it's not necessary to create another process for the subshell and keeping the variable changes from the higher block. A situation only when it can't be helped is when you place them on a pipeline since they are placed on a subshell by default, where not laspipe is set and commands are on the end, although using process substitutions are the way to go for it.

Comment: The `for` loop is already a compound command that groups its body; the subshell here is pointless.

Comment: @konsolebox, excellent points! My own scripts could probably do with a lot more `{}`'s :)