# saving output to a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

Script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 mydir="/bamboo/artifacts"
 cd "$mydir"
 job="-JOB1"

 for dir in */
    do
       bambooplan=`echo $dir | sed 's/\/$//g'`$job
       echo $bambooplan
    done
```

Output:

```
   LERST-TSTREDAPIDB2WIN4-JOB1
   LERST-TSTREDAPIDB2WIN5-JOB1
   CA-TSTALLSQLWIN3-JOB1
   CE-CSW-JOB1
   CE-SNAP-JOB1
```

I want to pass this to a file. I tried the commands below and it gives permission denied error. Could someone help me figure what I miss here?

```
echo $bambooplan > result.txt
$bambooplan > result.txt
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612603/redirecting-output-of-bash-for-loop. And http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/014

Comment: Your syntax is correct. Permission denied means you don't have write permission to `result.txt`, or the file doesn't exist and you don't have write permission to the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code with the first 'writing line' (`echo $bambooplan > result.txt`) and worked perfect for me, only i would change `echo $bambooplan > result.txt` to `echo $bambooplan >> result.txt`, otherwise, you will overwrite the entire file in each iteration, keeping only the last one.

Be aware that your code writes INSIDE `/bamboo/artifacts` and you wrote the file path as `/bamboo/artifacts`, an absolute path, not a relative one -> `bamboo/artifacts`, so, maybe, you're trying to write in a folder where you don't have writing permissions and need to `chmod` them.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect just to your defined file by using > as you specified or >> if file already already exists and contains data. Regarding to the permission, just exchange script's rights thru chmod command.

for instance :

```
chmod 755 scriptname
```

Same process to change output file's permission.

Comment: The script must already have the correct permissions, since he's executing it.